# How do I implement Toastr JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toastr

I am new to JS and not sure how to make this work on my page.  Below is what I have.  How must I make this alert show?

I added the source correctly but not sure how to render the alert.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Toast</title>
    <link href="toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="toastr.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    //toastr.info('Are you the 6 fingered man?')


    Command: toastr[success]("   ", "Settings Saved!")

    toastr.options: {
    "debug": false,
    "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
    "onclick": null,
    "fadeIn": 300,
    "fadeOut": 1000,
    "timeOut": 5000,
    "extendedTimeOut": 1000
    }
    });
    </script>
   </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I hope you've started with the [documentation](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr)

Comment: I did but I am not clear as to how to call the alert? Do I use a click event? I am new to JS as well.

Comment: You need to remove `Command:` before toastr

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Toastr is a very nice component, and you can show messages with theses commands:

```
// for success - green box
toastr.success('Success messages');

// for errors - red box
toastr.error('errors messages');

// for warning - orange box
toastr.warning('warning messages');

// for info - blue box
toastr.info('info messages');
```

If you want to provide a title on the toastr message, just add a second argument:

```
// for info - blue box
toastr.success('The process has been saved.', 'Success');
```

you also can change the default  behaviour using something like this:

```
toastr.options.timeOut = 3000; // 3s
```

See more on the [github of the project](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr).

### Edits

A sample of use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // show when page load
    toastr.info('Page Loaded!');

    $('#linkButton').click(function() {
       // show when the button is clicked
       toastr.success('Click Button');

    });

});
```

and a html:

```
<a id='linkButton'>Show Message</a>
```

Comment: Thanks.  But my question is how to use them in my html to show those messages.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, you already have setup it on your page right? just call those methods where you need to show a message :).. for sample, on the `$(document).ready(function() {...});` or any other event handler!

Comment: Thats what I mean.  How do I call them? I am sorry if this is obvious but I am new to JS.

Comment: can you give me a sample using my code in the question? I will really appreciate it.  thanks!

Comment: Somethoing like this? $('.show_hide').click(function () {
 // for success - green box
toastr.success('Success messages');
toastr.options.timeOut = 3000; // 3s
});

Comment: Thanks.  after copying your code, i got this: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined 

} (window, jQuery));

toastr.js (line 166)
SyntaxError: invalid label 

toastr.options: {

toast.html#toastr (line 28, col 7)

Comment: How do i change the location of toastr ?  I want it to shown in bottom center, i tried to put the options but they dont work it follows the default method options

Answer (score 12):

You dont need jquery-migrate. Summarizing previous answers, here is a working html:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <a id='linkButton'>ClickMe</a>
      
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
      
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/js/toastr.js"></script>
      
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        toastr.options.timeOut = 1500; // 1.5s
        toastr.info('Page Loaded!');
        $('#linkButton').click(function() {
           toastr.success('Click Button');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8):

I investigate i knew that the jquery script need to load in order that why it not worked in your case.
Because $ symbol mentioned in code not understand unless you load Jquery 1.9.1 at first.
Load like follows

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/js/toastr.js"></script>
```

Then it will work fine

Answer (score 5):

**This is a simple way to do it!**

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/js/toastr.js"></script>
<script>
function notificationme(){
toastr.options = {
            "closeButton": false,
            "debug": false,
            "newestOnTop": false,
            "progressBar": true,
            "preventDuplicates": true,
            "onclick": null,
            "showDuration": "100",
            "hideDuration": "1000",
            "timeOut": "5000",
            "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
            "showEasing": "swing",
            "hideEasing": "linear",
            "showMethod": "show",
            "hideMethod": "hide"
        };
toastr.info('MY MESSAGE!');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to do it!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Toaster Example</title>
    <!-- toastr -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <button id="btnInfo">Info</button>
    <button id="btnSuccess">Success</button>
    <button id="btnError">Error</button>
    <button id="btnWarning">Warning</button>

    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- toastr -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/js/toastr.js"></script>

    <!-- core script  -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // consts 
        const btnInfo = document.getElementById('btnInfo');
        const btnSuccess = document.getElementById('btnSuccess');
        const btnError = document.getElementById('btnError');
        const btnWarning = document.getElementById('btnWarning');

        // Event Listeners
        btnInfo.addEventListener('click', displayInfoToaster);
        btnSuccess.addEventListener('click', displaySuccessToaster);
        btnError.addEventListener('click', displayErrorToaster);
        btnWarning.addEventListener('click', displayWarningToaster);

        // functions
        function displayInfoToaster() {
            toastr.options.timeOut = 1500; // 1.5s 
            toastr.info('info messages');
        }

        function displaySuccessToaster() {
            toastr.options.timeOut = 1500; // 1.5s 
            toastr.success('Success messages');
        }

        function displayErrorToaster() {
            toastr.options.timeOut = 1500; // 1.5s 
            toastr.error('errors messages');
        }

        function displayWarningToaster() {
            toastr.options.timeOut = 1500; // 1.5s 
            toastr.warning('warning messages');
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add CDN Files of toastr.css and toastr.js**

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/js/toastr.js"></script>

function toasterOptions() {
    toastr.options = {
        "closeButton": false,
        "debug": false,
        "newestOnTop": false,
        "progressBar": true,
        "positionClass": "toast-top-center",
        "preventDuplicates": true,
        "onclick": null,
        "showDuration": "100",
        "hideDuration": "1000",
        "timeOut": "5000",
        "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
        "showEasing": "swing",
        "hideEasing": "linear",
        "showMethod": "show",
        "hideMethod": "hide"
    };
};


toasterOptions();
toastr.error("Error Message from toastr");
```

Comment: Is it necessary to put the options in a function?

Comment: No, It is not necessary.  Toastr will be applied with default Values. If you need any Customization on Toastr, then you can. If not, proceed to call Success, Error, Info,Warning Toastr's directly.